# ImportError: cannot import name asn1

Tags: python, python-2.4

i have installed pysnmp on centos using easy_install,
however when i import asn1 it does not work

```
[root@server ~]# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jun 18 2012, 08:55:23)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pysnmp import asn1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: cannot import name asn1
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pysnmp-4.2.2-py2.4.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pyasn1-0.1.3-py2.4.egg', '/usr/lib64/python24.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.4', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages']
>>>
```

i am trying to run this example http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/2.x/snmpagent.html

my goal is to read snmp traps sent by other devices and process them on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run an example for 2.x with version 4.x of the package. Find a 4.x example instead.